# Split view with green button does not work in macOS Sierra

Tags: mission-control, macos, split-view

When I try to use split view feature in macOS Sierra, I can not use the green button any more. Every help page found by google suggests I should click and hold the green button to activate split screen for the current window. The window would shrink and I could move it left or right and then choose an other open window to place it on the other side. This does not work with my MacBook on macOS Sierra.

I can use split view via mission control for windows already opened in full screen, thats's fine. But sometimes I might prefer to activate it directly from the current window without putting it to full screen first.

Edit: I have no 3rd party tools for windows management in use. I tried with Safari an Maps, both 1st party tools that do support the feature, as far as I know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to System Settings -> Mission Control activate the checkbox **displays have separate spaces**.

Log out and In and check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

That is how it should work. It seems like something is interfering with the button press. Try disabling any window management apps such as BetterTouchTool. Also try using a first-party app such as Finder to make sure the app itself is not the one modifying the green button functionality.

[image]

Comment: I have no window management tools (added that in my question now). And I tried it with Safari, Finder and Maps.